# Why efficiency of selection sort or Bubble or Insertion sort is said to be n^2 and not as n(n-1)/2

Tags: algorithm, performance, sorting, big-o

Suppose I have an array of descending Numbers(Worst Case scenario) Like:

Nums = {50,40,30,20,10} (size = 5)

Now If I use Selection sort (which would sort them in ascending):

Selection Sort Algorithm:

```
for(i=0; i<=size-2; i++)
{
    for(j=i+1; j<=size-1; j++)
    {
        if(Nums[i]>Nums[j])
       {
            temp=Nums[i]; 
            Nums[i]=Nums[j]; 
            Nums[j]=temp; 
       } 
    }
}
```

Now If we analyse the Number of Operations or Iterations performed, Here is how the indexes are compared

```
(OuterLoopIndex Vs InnerLoopIndex):

1st Iteration: 0 - 1,  0 - 2,  0 - 3,  0 - 4
2nd Iteration: 1 - 2,  1 - 3,  1 - 4
3rd Iteration: 2 - 3,  2 - 4
4th Iteration: 3 - 4
```

Now If add all the total number of operations in each iteration they are exactly
**10** (4 + 3 + 2 + 1) Which is Like Sum of N numbers whose formula is **N(N+1)/2** (basic math) but in our example here N is not the size its the last index of array which would be size-1 so here **N** would be **N-1**.

Hence we would get something like this if substitute **N=N-1** in **N(N+1)/2**

=> **(N-1)(N-1+1)/2**

=> **N(N-1)/2**

Same goes for Bubble and Insertion sort. So why efficiency of those sorting algorithms is said to be be n^2 and note n(n-1)/2 ?

when size=5 we would get 25 if we consider n^2, but only 10 when considering n(n-1)/2 ? Why/How n^2 is still considered as efficiency here ?

Comment: `O(n^2)` and `O(n*(n-1)/2)` are equivalent.

Comment: Read https://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In big-O notation only the most significant term counts, and constant coefficients are ignored:

```
O[n(n-1)/2] = O[n²/2 + n/2] = O[n²/2] = O(n²)
```

Comment: I think you have a typo on your right-most expression (I guess you meant O(n^2)).

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, @AmiTavory! Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

In big-O notation, you always take the upper limit and thus the terms that contributes the more, for example, n cube raised to power a large number will play a large role than n square to the same number and thus you ignore the lower order terms and thus don't mention then when mentioning the order in big-o notation.

Answer (score 0):

The statement in your question is not quite precise. It is not said to be *n<sup>2</sup>*, but rather *Θ(n<sup>2</sup>)*, i.e., something that grows with the same order as *n<sup>2</sup>*.

Your analysis above fits with it. For large enough *n*:

*n (n - 2) / 2 ≤ 2 n<sup>2</sup>*, so it is *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*,

but *n (n - 2) / 2 ≥ n<sup>2</sup> / 4*, so it is *Ω(n<sup>2</sup>)*.