# Why are only n/2 iterations considered for lower bound of selection sort?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity

From "Algorithms Unlocked" - Cormen, in Chapter 3- Algorithms for Sorting and Searching, under "Selection Sort".

The running time is Omega(n^2). This lower bound is calculated by considering n/2 iterations of the outer loop. Why n/2 iterations are considered?

Isn't the entire array traversed in all cases, including the lower-bound case? If yes, shouldn't 'n' be considered instead of n/2?

Edit1: That n/2 is considered even for the inner loop is not helping understand the logic.

Comment: It takes at least as long to do all the work as it does to do those n/2 iterations, so those n/2 iterations give us a lower bound. We don't need to consider all the iterations.

Comment: Are you saying in the case needing least work, iterating just n/2 times would suffice?
How is it assured that there is no element of lower value past n/2 position? How is it assured that elements after n/2 position are themselves already sorted? 
Btw, n/2 is considered even for the inner loop.
Can you please give an example?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39712257/why-efficiency-of-selection-sort-or-bubble-or-insertion-sort-is-said-to-be-n2-a

Comment: You don't seem to be understanding what a lower bound *is*. We are not trying to find the runtime of the case needing the least work. We are trying to find a function such that the algorithm does *at least that much work*, asymptotically speaking. We can do this by only considering some of the work done.

Comment: 0 would also be a lower bound, since the function does at least 0 work. It's not a very good lower bound, but it's a lower bound.

Comment: Thank you. By case needing least work, I meant best case, case where the algorithm finishes with the least amount of computations.

Comment: Thanks @user2357112.

Answer (score 3):

The logic is the following: Different iterations of outer loop have different lengths of inner loop.  In the first n/2 iterations of the outer loop we know that the inner loop has length >= n/2.  Thus, we know that total amount of work is greater than the amount of work for the first n/2 iterations which is greater than (n/2)*(n/2) = n^2/4, thus Omega(n^2).

If we considered entire outer loop, we would not be able to state that inner loop has much work to do because the last iteration of outer loop has inner loop of length 1, and we would get the estimate n*1.

For better understanding you should keep in mind the following two moments:

1. Definition of Omega(n^2).  It does not say that complexity is >= n^2.  It says that *there is* a constant C such that complexity >= C * n^2.  C might be equal 1, then >= n^2, or 100, then >= 100 * n^2, or 0.000001, then >= 0.000001 * n^2.  But since we've found that for selection sort we have >= (1/4)*n^2, we know that selection sort is Omega(n^2) with C equal 0.25.
2. In analyzing the complexity of selection sort we do not discuss "worst case" or "best case" scenarios.  In fact, the algorithm does not depend on data we are sorting and it is always performing exactly the same iterations in outer and inner loops. (To be precise: the only difference, depending on the data, is whether we perform the swap operation or not.  But we do not count the swap operation in the analysis.)  Thus, when we are talking about "first n/2 iterations" of the outer loop, we do not assume that the algorism was able to complete the job in n/2 iterations.  We just evaluate the amount of work done in the first n/2 iterations leaving the work in remaining iterations aside.

Comment: Thank you. 
I am still not able to follow why this case of the iterations-go-beyond (n/2) * (n/2) was considered for Omega(). 
Are you saying that the author was highlighting the point (along the complexity scale) where the algorithm reaches n^2 complexity. In other words, beyond this point (and these cases) it will anyhow be n^2 order?

Comment: When you're analyzing an algorithm, you can often discard some information or make assumptions to simplify the analysis. In this case, the author says part of the problem (half of the loop) is at least a certain amount (n/2) of work. Since part of the problem is Ω(n²), the whole problem must also be at least Ω(n²).

Comment: Thanks @dvorn & Matthew. That's helpful.